# IsValidLocale returns FALSE - how to overcome this?

Tags: windows, winapi, deployment, internationalization, locale

When run on a Spanish version of Windows XP my program invokes

```
LANGID langId = (LANGID) MAKELANGID( LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_DEFAULT );
LCID locale = MAKELCID( language, SORT_DEFAULT ); 
BOOL isValid = IsValidLocale( locale, LCID_INSTALLED );
```

IsValideLocale() return FALSE when asked about English locale. Obviously something must be tuned in Windows to change this behaviour. What exactly should I do?

I understand that it's not completely a programming question but rather a deployment question. Still I think it will be better off here than anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is that you use `SUBLANG_DEFAULT` option. Try using `SUBLANG_NEUTRAL` or use something more concrete, say `SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US`.